# Nginx server multiple site and domain redirection (on same port/different port)

Tags: http, nginx, https, server

I am trying to host multiple unrelated sites on the same nginx server. How do I edit the http.conf and the https.conf file in order to make it work?

ORIGINAL HTTP.CONF

```
server {
    listen 2333;
    server_name port1.example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.\*) http://port1.example.com/$1 permanent;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/http_access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/http_error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(htaccess|htpasswd) {
        deny all;
    }

    # set long EXPIRES header on static assets
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
    }

}
```

ORIGINAL HTTPS.CONF

```
server {
    listen 4433 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/port2.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/port2.example.com.key;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/https_access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/https_error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(htaccess|htpasswd) {
        deny all;
    }

    # set long EXPIRES header on static assets
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
    }

}
```

My port 4433 is on SSL obviously. How can I get port `2333` to work only on `port1.example`.com and port `4433` to work only on `port2.example.com` It's better if 2333 can be served on SSL, too.

Comment: what do you exactly want? your port1.example.com is already hosted on port 2333 and port2.example.com is served by server listening on port 4333. But my concern is http request are run on port 80 by default and https on port 443. Please clarify what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @Satys But this configuration won't work. Can you help editing?

Comment: Yeah sure, I just don't completely understand your requirement and setup

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for viewing. I ended up using Nginx and it was way faster setting up using multiple .conf files in the `/etc/nginx/conf` folder.